# Where do I ask general architecture and framework questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

Where do I ask general architecture and framework questions?

I want to build a content management system in .NET/C# that will work to a site similar to reddit and social media. I have a lot of specific questions while I'm, getting started that aren't actual programming questions. Where would I ask these?